# Alerts/Recommendations on Azure Database Overview page

Tags: database, azure, logging, alert

Does anyone know where in azure I can collect these sorts of alerts/recommendations found on the Overview page of any Azure SQL Database? Looking for where they might be for logs and use for automation.

[DB Overview Alerts/Recommendations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXcS3.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can create **Alerts** in Azure SQL Database for Alerts and use **Action Group** to get these alerts using **Webhook** action type.

> You can use webhooks to route an Azure alert notification to other
> systems for post-processing or custom actions. You can use a webhook
> on an alert to route it to services that send SMS messages, to log
> bugs, to notify a team via chat or messaging services, or for various
> other actions.

[image]

Follow [Create alerts for Azure SQL Database and Azure Synapse Analytics using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/alerts-insights-configure-portal) tutorial to implement the same.